# when login multiple users at same time PHP SESSION conflicting

Tags: php, apache

I am facing issue in my created CRM. when multiple user login at same time. data conflict with other users. How I resolve the issue.

Comment: are you using any framework or working on core PHP ?

Comment: I am working on core PHP

Comment: https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/webdb/ch08_03.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can either limit the user session by storing the session value in DB for that particular user.